# How to go from colab to local notebook with same environment

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, virtual-environment

I have created a notebook in google colab where I am training a neural network.
In colab all imports and installations are problem free. However, when I create a local copy of the jupyter-notebook, there are a lot of issues with missing packages and missing requirements.
Is there any way I can get the same colab environment where my code works, and use the GPU on the local machine simultaneously? Or any other solution where I don't have to spend a lot of time on fixing package installations and missing requirements